# Unnatural silence in New Pokemon Snap

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

I've been playing New Pokemon Snap for a few days, and it seems to be lacking sounds in many places I would expect it to have some, and seems to ignore my sound settings in other ways. Here are some specifics:

#### During a research expedition

- Teleporting makes a sound, even with all of my sound options muted.
- The characters commenting on your photos make a sound, as long as voices aren't muted
- There is no background music
- Pokemon make no sounds
- The camera makes no sounds
- The pokeflute (which is called something else but I don't remember what) makes no sound
- All other tools I have unlocked make no sounds
- There is no background music

#### During photo evaluation

- A line plays when Professor Mirror speaks, even with voices muted
- There is no background music
- There are no other sounds at all

#### At camp

- Background music plays, even when music is muted
- Voice clips play at times, even when voices are muted
- No other sound effects are audible

#### In the audio settings menu

- Changing the "Voices" volume setting plays a voice clip, but the volume of the voice clip is the same at all levels
- Changing the other two volume settings has no accompanying sound
- No sound effects in general play when navigating the menu or changing settings

As I've mentioned a few times, I'm aware of the audio settings portion of the menu but changing those settings does not fix any of the problems (in fact, the only part of the game that seems affected by any of the settings is the comments by various characters when you take a "good" picture). I have to imagine that this isn't intentional? That most people are not experiencing this overwhelming lack of audio? If anybody has, is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have since fixed this issue, and all of my audio is now working as I expect it to. Reinstalling the software was the solution, specifically following these steps:

1. From the Switch Home Menu, press + to open the New Pokemon Snap software options
2. Go to Manage Software and select Archive Software
3. After it is archived, the icon should still be visible
4. Enter the options again by pressing +
5. Go to Software Update and select Re-Download Software